# Can't get jQuery :not selector to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

If you type a character inside the input field of the jsbin below, a div will slide down. On click of any elements other than div.wrap and its children, I want this div to slide back up. I can not seem to get this right. It keeps doing the opposite of what I want.

http://jsbin.com/sobecume/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

***JS***

```
$('.blah').keyup(function(){
  $('.blah2').slideDown();
});

$('body:not("#wrap")').click(function(){
  console.log("click!");
  var display = $('.blah').css('display');
  if (display !== 'none') {
    $('.blah2').slideUp();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can craft a selector to check against an element's ancestors (I think?).

Try this:

```
$('*').click(function(){
  if($(this).closest('#wrap').length>0){return false;}
  console.log("click!");
  var display = $('.blah').css('display');
  if (display !== 'none') {
    $('.blah2').slideUp();
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/sobecume/3

Comment: Thanks for the help. Could you explain how the first two lines work?

Comment: @UncleSlug The '*' selector selects any element on the page.  The if() travels up the DOM from that element checking for a #wrap id. If it finds one, it returns false, else the rest of the function executes.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code actually works fine, the problem is that your HTML basically is only your wrap container. Check out this jsbin where I added a box that is clearly separate from the wrap div:

http://jsbin.com/sobecume/5/